# On the use of "Ad" + section number in a work of German philosophy from the early 1700's

Tags: standard-german, book, blackletter

I am trying to get familiar with a work by German philosopher Christian Wolff. The book is called *Vernünftige Gedanken von Gott, der Welt und der Seele des Menschen, auch allen Dingen überhaupt*. I have a PDF copy of the third edition, from 1733.

The work is divided into 426 sections. At the end of many sections, though, there is a line like this:

**Ad §. 169.**

At first I thought that these were references to other sections within this same work, but it doesn't seem like that can be right, since some of the references are to section numbers that fall beyond the 426 listed in the book. The "Ad." may be a Latin abbreviation, as there are some Latin words in the text (the majority is the old German script).

Below I have included two screenshots of what I'm talking about. Does anyone know what these references mean in general (and what they could mean for Wolff in particular)? Many thanks.

[image: section 10]
[image]

Comment: Im gezeigten Bild sind keine Punkte hinter dem "Ad".

Comment: Definitely footnotes of some kind. _Ad_ is a full Latin word, not an abbreviation.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104161/is-it-correct-to-start-a-sentence-with-ad-question-one

Comment: Thank you for your help. After some more looking and checking the ideas here, I think that the work I've been looking at is something like Wolff's own commentary on his _Vernünftige Gedanken_. The "Ad." things seem to be references to the original work, which contains around 1,000 sections.

Comment: Can you correct the dots in your post, if I happen to be right? Or are there really some dots? That's important for the question whether it is an abbrev. or nor.

Comment: Changed the dots.

Answer (score 5):

Als Nichtlateiner kenne ich nur ganz wenige, lateinische Phrasen, etwa "ad hominem" und darin ist das "ad" keine Abkürzung, wie auch der Screenshot 2 Verwendungen ohne Punkt zeigt, wärend ansonsten an Punkten nicht gespart wird.

In "ad hominem" heißt "ad" soviel wie "zu" (zur Person), und also wird das **Ad** für **Zu** stehen, also "Zu Paragraph 18.20" im Zusammenhang.

Comment: Ja, so auch [der Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ad).

Answer (score 1):

Latin *ad* (or German *zu, zu[m] Punkt*) is used similar to *re* (*bezüglich = bzgl., in Sachen / in der Sache/Angelegenheit*) – as popularized by email subject lines – in sophisticated German. The former is most often used with numbered items as in enumerated or ordered lists, but sections or paragraphs in this case, the latter more with spelled out topics, and *re* is even less common than *ad* in contemporary German.

In recent texts, I’ve only seen *ad* being used by older professors of philosophy or linguistics and by people who wish they were one – they also tend to write stuff like *qua* for *durch* or *per*.

You seem to have basically figured out the answer yourself prior to asking, the problem was just that the frame of context, which should have been established in a foreword or introduction, was unavailable to you.

Comment: Als ich in den Neunzigern Mathematik studiert habe, würde das von einigen (zugegeben, Älteren) auch noch ganz selbstverständlich benutzt, wenn eine Liste von Eigenschaften abzuarbeiten war. Ebenso wie „N.b.“ (ich erinnere mich leider nicht mehr, ob mit oder ohne Punkten) gebräuchlich war.